# Symfony Propel 1.4 first rule overwrite a next rule in the routing.yml

Tags: routes, symfony-1.4

I have several rules in routing.yml

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: cars, action: index }

letters:
  url: /:letter
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options:
    model: MyCarmodelPeer
    type: object
  param:
    module: cars
    action: alphalist
    linkmode: "@letters"
  requirements:
    letter: "([A-Z])"
    sf_method: [get]

show:
  url: /:slug
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options:
    model: MyCarmodelPeer
    type: object
  param:
     module: cars
     action: view
  linkmode: "@show"
  requirements:
   slug: "([A-Z]|0-9)"
   sf_method: [get]


default:
   url:   /:module/:action/*
```

Route to the main page works as expected.
But the letters and show routes are not working properly.
If the first route letters then it works normally, and the route show does not work. In this case, I have an error **Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/bmw-1-series-187-5-120-2004-2008" (/).**
If I rearrange them, then letters point to an action view, but it should point to the action alphalist.

Why do they overwrite each other?

**UPDATED**

Here is a case, on an other website, that worked.

```
letters:
  url: /:letter
  param:
    module: define
    action: alphalist
    linkmode: "@letters"
    cachename: "letters"
    layer: "@default-layer"
  requirements:
    letter: "([A-Z]|0-9)"

disclaimer:
  url: /medical-disclaimer/
  param:
    module: define
    action: disclaimer

default-layer:
  url: /:search
  param:
    module: define
    action: word
    linkmode: "@default-layer"
    cachename: "default-layer"
  options:
    segment_separators: ['', '/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They override each other because the way symfony will try to resolve it is the same.

You defined `url: /:slug` for `show`, which mean the url will be `/` and something after, like `/foo`, `/toto`. But you also defined this kind of url for `letters` `/:letter`, which can match for `/foo` and `/toto` too !

That's why when you define the `show` route at first, `show` works but `letters` not. And vice versa.

The way you have to fix it is to define **unique** url for each route. Something like:

```
letters:
  url: /letters/:letter

show:
  url: /show/:slug
```

This way, each route won't *eat* each other because of the prefix (letters & show).

**Edit:**

I got the point, your requirement could help symfony to match a url even if there are both with `/:slug`.

For the `letter` route, your requirement allow only one letter upercase. But for the `show` route, it allow one letter upcase OR one number. Which is wrong regarding your url (`bmw-1-series-187-5-120-2004-2008`).

Try with this requirement, for the `show` route (and you can remove the prefix I gave before):

```
  requirements:
   slug: "([a-z0-9\-]+)"
```

Comment: This strange when i tryed to apply your solution, but even after i have cleared my cache, the problem didn't solved. But in other project routing like my is working. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Did you change the way you build url? Do they have `/letters/` and `/show/` in your url?

Comment: Yes, they are. I changed them as mentioned.

Comment: You will have the same problem with `default-layer` and by the way your update does show the updated `letters` route. You got the same error after applying my change?

Comment: Of course I apply your change. See screenshot attahed [link1](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44764980/01.png), [link2](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44764980/02.png),[link3](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44764980/03.png),[link4](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44764980/04.png). My updated question just illustrates that on other site this kind of routing is work. In my case this not.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works and without prefix too, i tottaly forget about regexp. Thanks one more time.